# (rpg?) dialogue system in HTML5 & Javascript - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dialog

I want to make a text based dialogue system giving the user multiple choices to choose from.

In terms of UI, i'd like it to be almost identical to something like this, but this is done in flash and isn't multiple choice:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/make-an-rpg-style-text-system-for-your-next-game--active-3678

Since I have no experience in flash, i'd like to see if it could be done in JS/jQuery.

I don't think i'd have a hard time replicating the UI at face value, but as far as the scrolling text goes, I'm not sure. Possibly CSS3?

My only ideas that might make it work would be, using a constructor for the people in the conversations, and then of course another for the conversation itself then display the "conversation" and user choices in a JQ dialog window? Other then that, I'm lost.

I know that there's dialog systems out there, but I haven't seen any in JS and i'm wondering if anyone has done something like this or at least attempted it.

As always, thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** I think I was a bit vague - if this *can* be done, *how* can it be done. 
Is there any tuts or books/pdfs for something similar?

Comment: Yes, you can, but a game should be much more than dialog system, which is probably the easiest part of a game.

Comment: Yes, obviously. However, if you intend to make a somewhat - text-based RPG with canvas using mainly static images, dialogue and story line play a bigger part then most graphic intensive games. So, i suppose my real question would be. if so, how can it be done?

Comment: You should narrow down to specific problem. Layouting using CSS is not a difficult task. The real question is, what is your layout?

Answer (score 0):

I got something working pretty quickly using [Yarn](https://github.com/infiniteammoinc/Yarn) (editor) and [bondage.js](https://github.com/jhayley/bondage.js) (client). bondage 0.5.5 doesn't support all the features of Yarn but it's more than enough to get started.